# insert , delete in C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I want to know the differences of using

```
DB.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(..);
and
DB.MyTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(..);
----------------------------------
DB.MyTable.DeleteOnSubmit(..);
and
DB.MyTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(..);
```

I also want to know how to use , can somebody explain me with some example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254691/difference-between-linqtosql-insertonsubmit-and-insertallonsubmit

Comment: Look at the parameter the functions take!

Comment: @Tim Schmelter , I know how to use InsertOnSubmit() and DeleteOnSubmit() . But I don't know how to get the object for InsertAllOnSubmit() and DeleteAllOnSubmit() .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InsertOnSubmit(yourSingleData) and InsertAllOnSubmit(yourMultipleData as List)
```

To delete single data ,

```
var obj = Db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeData == "something").SingleOrDefault();
Db.MyTable.DeleteOnSubmit(obj);
```

To delete multiple data ,

```
var obj = Db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeData == "something").ToList();
Db.MyTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

In LinqToSql, where a context derives from `DataContext`, the difference is whether or not to submit a specific individual entity, or a collection of them. They would be used like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext()) {
  context.Things.InsertOnSubmit(new Thing { ... })
}
```

Where you would populate instances of `Thing` ready for persistence.

And in the case of the second (inserting all), you would provide a collection instead.